# How to install Hadoop using Ambari setup?

Tags: json, hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I tried to install Hadoop on 3 node cluster using ambari_setup.sh. I have successfully started ambari-server on NODE_1 and ambari-agent is running on all 3 nodes.

I have also pushed blueprint using:

> root@host curl -H "X-Requested-By: ambari" -X POST -d @blueprint.json
>   -u admin:admin HOST_NAME:8080/api/v1/blueprints/blueprints-c1

But while installing using given below command I am getting following given below error.

> > [root@host]# curl -H "X-Requested-By: ambari" -X POST -d @hostmapping.json -u admin:admin
> >     HOST_NAME:8080/api/v1/clusters/blueprints-c1 {
> >     "status" : 400,   "message" : "The properties [host-groups] specified
> >     in the request or predicate are not supported for the resource type
> >     Cluster."

Given below is the hostmapping.json file I am using

```
> { "blueprint":"blueprints-c1",  "host-groups":[
>     { "name":"host_group_1",
>       "hosts":[ { "fqdn":"NODE_1" } ] },
>     { "name":"host_group_2",
>       "hosts":[ { "fqdn":"NODE_2" } ] },
>     { "name":"host_group_3",
>       "hosts":[ { "fqdn":"NODE_3" } ] } ] }
```

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake here: properties **[host-groups]**

It should be **[host_groups]**

Comment: Don't see any difference ?

Comment: @technico,  I see, you don't?

Comment: Seen with fresh eyes. My bad !

Answer (score 0):

You need to push the blueprint.json and the hostmapping.json. This need to be 2 seperate files and 2 seperate API-Calls. Did u do that?

Maybe you can specify what you done so far befor u get the exeception. Than we can tell you if you missed something